# pandas.apply changing the dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Here is the sample DataFrame, which has two columns. First one is a character and the second one is a datetime.

```
df = DataFrame([['960958','2013-01-24 00:00:00'], ['960918','2013-01-24 00:00:00']],columns=['col1','col2'])
df.col2 = pd.to_datetime(df.col2,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

now I am trying to print the data, first row is printing properly where as the send row is printing incorrectly as col1 is converting to date and printing.

```
def printdata(line):
    print line
df.apply(printdata,axis=1)
```

Please help on this, what went wrong in my coding and how to correct it.

here is the output below

```
#Output
col1                 960958
col2    2013-01-24 00:00:00
Name: 0, dtype: object
col1   1996-09-18
col2   2013-01-24
Name: 1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
Out[290]: 
0    None
1    None
dtype: object
```

If you observe the output line 3 and line 6 dtype is different and line 1 which is printing correctly where as line 4, printing as date which is not correct. it should print as same as line 1.

Comment: I know, I can print df directly, where as I am processing data by sending the as a line but, due to miss match in the datatype I am facing an error.

Comment: Sorry can't reproduce nor understand your real problem, please post what you see in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 0.16.2

IIRC this is the same is as [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9477) and was fixed in 0.16.0

```
In [5]: df = DataFrame([['960958','2013-01-24 00:00:00'], ['960918','2013-01-24 00:00:00']],columns=['col1','col2'])

In [6]: df.col2 = pd.to_datetime(df.col2,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

In [7]: In [6]: def printdata(line):
       ...:     print line
       ...:

In [8]: In [7]: df.apply(printdata,axis=1)
col1                 960958
col2    2013-01-24 00:00:00
Name: 0, dtype: object
col1                 960918
col2    2013-01-24 00:00:00
Name: 1, dtype: object
Out[8]: 
0    None
1    None
dtype: object
```